# Mono/MVC5/EF6/PostgreSQL application failed when upgrade from mono 5.8 to 5.14

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, mono

I have an application, runs on Mono with Mvc5, EF6 and PostgreSQL Npgsql provider. It works fine on mono 5.8. But it doesn't work with mono 5.14. It throws an exception

```
"System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key".
```

I have wrote a simple test code to reproduce this problem.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Model1 model1 = new Model1();

        var query = from b in model1.mx_busi_info
                    select b;

        foreach (var b in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(b.busi_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

The full exception stack trace is:

```
    Unhandled Exception:
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'MethodCallTranslator' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryInsert (TKey key, TValue value, System.Collections.Generic.InsertionBehavior behavior) [0x00008] in <2943701620b54f86b436d3ffad010412>:0
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key, TValue value) [0x00000] in <2943701620b54f86b436d3ffad010412>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator.InitializeMethodTranslators () [0x00031] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+MethodCallTranslator..cctor () [0x00014] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter+<GetTranslators>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00345] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.InitializeTranslators () [0x00050] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter..cctor () [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.CreateExpressionConverter () [0x0000c] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan (System.Nullable`1[T] forMergeOption) [0x0008d] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass7[T].<GetResults>b__6 () [0x0000b] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T] (System.Func`1[TResult] func, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, System.Boolean startLocalTransaction, System.Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) [0x0008a] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass7[T].<GetResults>b__5 () [0x00033] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult] (System.Func`1[TResult] operation) [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[T].GetResults (System.Nullable`1[T] forMergeOption) [0x00093] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
  at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[T].<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0 () [0x00000] in <b7b192e5a05f4f14a14aa0d5b14aeeeb>:0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have been affected by [this regression](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/9996).

But [a fix in Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/10452) has already been merged.

You will probably need to wait for the next 5.16 release which may have received this bugfix as a backport.

Comment: That is exactly the problem. I also checked the mono source code and find this bug. So I will try this bug fix and do more test. Thank you very much!